# How to get selected value from dynamically created checkboxlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problem getting selected value from CheckBoxList that I'm creating dynamically. On button click, I'm trying to get the selected checkbox value but I don't know this can get done. Below is the code that I've tried.

**Class.cs**

```
private void PopulateCheckBoxes()
        {

            LeaveController contLeave = new LeaveController();

            Models.Leave l = new Models.Leave();
            l.lr = contLeave.GetAllReasons(); //Getting values from database into list


            ListItem listc = new ListItem();

            foreach (var item in l.lr)
            {

                listc.Value = item.Id;
                listc.Text = item.Title;
                listc.Selected = item.ischecked;

                lst.Items.Add(new ListItem(listc.Text, listc.Value, listc.Selected));
            }

            chkboxpanel.Controls.Add(lst);

        }

protected void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Here i want to get the value of the selected checkbox from the list
}
```

**View.aspx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="chkboxpanel" name="ChkPanel" runat="server">
.....
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: where is the code for getting selected checkbox ?

Comment: Make sure `PopulateCheckBoxes()` is run on every Page Load, and that includes a PostBack. Then you can use FindControl to locate your Dynamic Control and Cast it to a CheckBoxList.